# cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code

Tags: python, opencv

I am not able to run cv2 .read() in python

Every time I run a simple code just to see myself from my webcam. It gives a strange error which I am not able to solve and I've almost searched a lot about it.
I only want to capture my video through webcam.

This is my code which is probably fine according to me.

```
import cv2
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = vid.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('my_frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Everytime I run this code it gives the following error -

```
_, frame = vid.read()
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

I am stuck what to do to resolve this problem. I've searched a lot across the platform.

edit: I think my webcam is working fine as when I execute the code the code runs and opens a window and shows the image from webcam but the image is grey and it works only for a second or two. It immediately shows the error.

My pip version is 21.1.1.
List of packages -

```
Package               Version
--------------------- --------
numpy                 1.20.3
opencv-contrib-python 4.5.2.52
Pillow                8.2.0
pip                   21.1.1
pywin32               300
setuptools            56.2.0
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try without the ``_,``?

Comment: yeah, I have tried by replacing that variable too.

Comment: Could you try to run this example from OpenCV site: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html It gives you a feedback, if camera is not ready.

Comment: You trying to use external tutorials (it is outdated, created in 2013). Ref: #17016
Use OpenCV documentation instead: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d89/tutorial_py_orb.html

Comment: Could you open a command/bash console, run two commands `pip -V` and `pip list` and add the output to your question. Unles the problem is camera access failure, the versions of the packages are important for understanding the problem.

Comment: your code is working totally fine on my computer.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz I executed the example from the OpenCV site it shows the same error the same thing happens.

Comment: @programandoconro yeah, other youtuber are running the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

- The first two lines don't get an error.
- The third line, where the (_,) is, no matter how many underscores, 2, 3, or 4, it still belts out the same error.
- replacing (_,) with return keyword will belt out errors.
- enclosing `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` with `open()` will still get errors.
- even when uninstalling and reinstalling OpenCV, it still does, in opencv-python 4.5.2.52.
- Sub-line "ret" does not work in that script.
- replacing (_,) with return keyword would still have errors.
- deleting (_,) will still get the same error.
- `cv2` can display already taken photos fine, but not real-time in the line of code(somehow).
- Several tutorials, despite their updated dates, their code does not work beyond *(ret/s/etc.), frame = (cap/vid).read()*
- enclosing the first variable assignment with open() will enter a field of more errors.

If that's the case, and one [tutorial](https://www.studytonight.com/post/capture-videos-and-images-with-python-part2) says the `vid.read()` will return a tuple, then there's bias. `print(vid)` would return something like `<VideoCapture 02D32370>`.

Using a text file, like

```
file=open('C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\New folder\\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw.txt')
```

and `print(file)`, it returns

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\New folder\\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

before `text=file.read()` and `print(text`).

OpenCV works fine displaying static images on my computer, but not recording series of images in one set(video).

- On my computer, there's no way other than using other modules.

**Edit:**
Despite what I said above, you need to replace `0` in `videocapture` with `0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW`, which basically translates to index difference (n) plus default camera index number.

Comment: `0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW` worked completely fine! Thanks.

Comment: Somehow, it takes plain old basic equations ( for example, 1+1, 2+2, 3+1, etc) and numbers as if it was just stated as None condition.

Answer (score 2):

try replacing this line:

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

with

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Comment: I don't know exactly why it work (for me) but I had the same error message and after research, I found solution - put cv2.CAP_DSHOW into VideoCapture() as second parameter